# Find all holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{3}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that
$f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{3}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

What I did:

Rewriting it

$f(\frac{1}{n})=3 \frac{1}{n}$

shows that the function $g(z):=3z$ fulfills the requirement.
I was searching for other functions that would fit. But then I got the hint that g is the only function that can fulfill the requirement, and I just need to show that there are no other functions.

I am really struggling with proving this.
Would be thankful if someone could show me how to do it.

Comment: The function $\frac{f(z)}{z}-3$ is holomorphic (since $f(0) = 0$ by continuity) and has zeroes at $\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots$, which accumulate to $0$. So by general theory of holomorphic functions, $\frac{f(z)}{z}-3$ is identically $0$.

Comment: @mathworker21 It is simpler to look at $f(z)-3z$, you don't have to worry about the removable singularity.

Comment: @Gary lol, no idea why i did $f(z)/z-3$, thanks

Comment: The short answer is: apply the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) with $f(z)$ as given, $g(z)=3z$, $D=\mathbb C$ and $S=\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 If I understand correct, you did use the Identity Theorem. So I just say, assume there is another function h, then  set ${w \in \mathbb{C}: h(w)-3w=0}$ has a accumulation point (zero), we get the equality $h(w)-3w \equiv 0$. Therefor the only function is $g(z)=3z$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Gary Thank you!